# Why do I get a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'char[]' to 'string' [C# programs]"

Tags: c#, string, linq, type-conversion

... when I try this in C#:

```
string reversedName;
reversedName = name.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray();
```

But not when I try this:

```
string reversedName = new string (name.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
```

? And when I try adding chaining a To.String() to the end of the first method, the Runtime doesn't throw an exception but returns: `System.Char[]`

I'm looking for an explanation on why the compiler seems to not be able to implicitly convert char[] to string:
* except when, apparently, calling `new string`,
* even when we chain the `ToString()` function to the end there.

Comment: `char[]` and `string` are different types... C# isn't C/C++

Comment: Because a string is not an array of characters in C#. The compiler seems to not be able because it doesn't make sense. Keep your languages straight.

Comment: Obviously the second example is a constructor. So you know why that works right? Why didn't the C# team make an implicit operator conversion from a char[]? Probably because they had a constructor and USUALLY an implicit converstion is NOT what you want.

Comment: @aquinas Okay, that's a good explanation (for a C# noob), My takeaway: different standards of converibility for constructors and for ordinary assignment, which, yes, makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try

```
string reversedName = new string (name.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
```

you are creating **string** with its constructor. As you can see, first parameter is array of chars: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131424(v=vs.110).aspx

But here

```
reversedName = name.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray();
```

you are returning an `array` (with ***.ToArray()*** at the end), which is obviously not assignable to variable of type `string`.

Calling `ToString()` on `array` will print its type `System.Char[]`, as you already noticed.

Answer (score 1):

The ToString() on an Char Array object will return `System.Char[]` because it's the default and expected behavior. The compiler cannot assume that you want to join every char into one string, and return that string.

The correct way is to use `new string(char[])`.

You can also always use a Extension class to add a extension method.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ConvertToString(this char[] array)
    {
        return new string(array);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string s = array.ConvertToString();
```

Comment: I guess the compiler makes the assumption that I want to convert every character into a single string only when I use it in a (string) constructor. Correct?

Comment: Yes. Actually, using the string constructor, the compiler does not need assume that - you are explicit telling it to do that, because there's no ambiguity in that case